# Find unique pairs in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, find, unique

Let's assume I have the following matrix:

```
A = [1 1 2 1;1 2 2 1;2 1 3 0;2 2 2 0;3 1 2 1]
```

Where the first column is an index and the next two an interaction and the last one a logic saying yes or no.
So know I would like to generate the following heat map based on the interactions. "X" axis represents interactions and "Y" axis represents index.

```
   1-2  1-3  2-2
1   1   NaN   1
2  NaN   0    0
3   1   NaN  NaN
```

My current approach:

```
B = sortrows(A,[2,3]);
```

Afterwards I apply find for each row and column individually.

Is there a function similar to `unique` which can check for two columns at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way, using `unique(...,'rows')`:

```
A = [1 1 2 1; 1 2 2 1; 2 1 3 0; 2 2 2 0; 3 1 2 1]; % data
[~, ~, jj] = unique(A(:,[2 3]),'rows'); % get interaction identifiers
B = accumarray([A(:,1) jj], A(:,4), [], @sum, NaN); % build result, with NaN as fill value
```

This gives

```
B =
     1   NaN     1
   NaN     0     0
     1   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>> A

A =

     1     1     2     1
     1     2     2     1
     2     1     3     0
     2     2     2     0
     3     1     2     1

>> [C, IA, IC] = unique(A(:, [2, 3]), 'rows')

C =

     1     2
     1     3
     2     2

IA =

     1
     3
     2

IC =

     1
     3
     2
     3
     1
```

`C` is a set of unique pairs. `IA` is the corresponding index of `C` (i.e., `C == A(IA, [2, 3])`). `IC` is the corresponding index of each row (i.e., `A(:, [2, 3]) == C(IC, :)`).

Answer (score 1):

this is a possible solution  with the aid of @Jeon 's answer(**Updated**):

```
A = [1 1 2 1;1 2 2 1;2 1 3 0;2 2 2 0;3 1 2 1]
[~,IA,idx] = unique(A(:, [2, 3]), 'rows');
r = max(A(:,1));
c = numel(IA);
out= NaN(r,c );
out(sub2ind([r ,c], A(:,1),idx)) = A(:,4)
```

Comment: Psst: `out NaN(r,c)` is a bit more elegant :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks. changed to NaN()